# How to do binning in matrix data

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, statistics, data, matrix-factorisation

I have some data like

```
     hr1 hr2 hr3 hr4 hr5 hr6 hr7
usr1 1  0   0   0   0   0   0
usr2 0  1   1   0   0   0   0
usr3 0  1   0   0   0   0   0
usr4 1  0   0   0   0   0   0
usr5 1  1   1   1   1   1   1
```

How to categorize this data in bins like hr1-hr3 and hr4-hr7 or any other bins

Comment: Please clarify the question.Do you want to count the total by column? And in which language at least?

Comment: You can use the Hamming distance and some clustering algorithm.